# Unable to exclude folders from war file using regex

Tags: regex, maven-2

I'm attempting to exclude all of the js/backbone directories with the exception of the libs directory from my war file. My pom file entry is as follows:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <packagingExcludes>
                %regex[js/backbone/[^l].*/]
            </packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Unfortunately, no directories are being excluded. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!..)` to exclude the lib directory:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>
            %regex[js/backbone/(?!libs/).*]
        </packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

`(?!libs/)` means *not followed by `libs/`*

Comment: That removed everything in the js/backbone/ directory, including /lib directory.

Comment: @rustic1206: Try without the slash `(?!lib)`

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: Removing the slash as js/backbone/(?!libs).* worked. However, there were some files at the root of js/backbone there were also removed. Do I need another statement to keep those files?

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: I figured it out!! Doing, js/backbone/(?!libs|.*-build-.*.js).* worked!! Thanks for the help!!